# Countably many oracle Turing machines?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, oracle-machines

In Sipser's text, when proving that there exists an oracle $A$ such that $P^A \ne NP^A$, he writes:

> Let $M_1, M_2, \ldots$ be a list of all polynomial time oracle TMs.

I understand that there are countably many Turing machines, but aren't there uncountably many oracles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ possible oracles, but when fixing an oracle $A\subseteq \Sigma^*$, there are only countably many Turing machines $M^A$ with access to the oracle $A$.

Remember that a Turing machine with access to some oracle is defined in the same manner as a normal Turing machine, but with an additional operation (they can query the oracle). They have a special tape on which they can write a query, and say, three additional special states $q_{ask},q_{yes},q_{no}$. Upon entering $q_{ask}$, if $s\in\Sigma^*$ is the content of the query tape, the machine enters either $q_{yes}/q_{no}$, depending on whether or not $s\in A$.

Nothing stops us from encoding such machines as strings, in the same way we encode regular Turing machines, hence we only have countably many such machines.

Comment: Are you saying that "Let $M_1$,$M_2$,… be a list of all polynomial time oracle TMs." means: fix an oracle $A$ and consider all TMs that have $A$ as an oracle? I was reading this as "consider all TMs with all possible oracles"...

Comment: First option (otherwise as you said, you have uncountably many).

Answer (score 0):

There are uncountably many oracles. ​ However, those are sold separately:

The oracle Turing machine only comes with an interface for

interacting with whatever oracle one might choose to use it with.