# Is the set of languages recognized by a Turing machine with an oracle countable?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, oracle-machines

I am currently taking a class in complexity theory and I am struggling with this question.

We define a TM with Oracle per. Sipser 6.18 as:

"An oracle for language $B$ is an external device that is capable of reporting whether any string $w$ is a member of $B$. An oracle Turing machine is a modified Turing machine that has the additional capability of querying an oracle. We write $M^b$ to describe an oracle Turing machine that has an oracle for language B."

I think that the answer is potentially false. We know that the set of languages is uncountable and suppose we had a Oracle Turing machine that accepts if the oracle answers YES, reject otherwise. Wouldn't that mean that then the set of languages recognized by TM with an oracle be uncountable?

Comment: Yes, it depends on what the set of potential oracles is.

Comment: [duplicate](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67679/countably-many-oracle-turing-machines/67680#67680)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every language can be accepted by a Turing machine with an appropriate oracle, for example an oracle for the very language you want to accept. So if you understand "languages recognized by a Turing machine with an oracle" in this way, then certainly their number is uncountable.

Another way to understand this phrase is the you *fix the oracle* and then ask how many languages are recognized by a Turing machine with access to this specific oracle. In this case the number of languages is countable, since there are countably many ways to specify a Turing machine.