# Prove that there aren't any complete languages

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, turing-completeness

Prove that there isn't a complete language over a given alphabet $\Sigma$. That is, there is no $C \subseteq \Sigma^*$ such that every $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is Turing-reducible to $C$.

**Attempt:** Let $L$ be a language and let $\overline{L}$ be its complement. And let's say there is a reduction between $L$ and $\overline{L}$. So, we can say that if there is a word $w$ in $L$ it's also in $\overline{L}$.
But that's a contradiction because $\overline{L}$ is all words that are not in $L$.

I'm not sure if this answer is correct though.

Comment: Turing completeness, as you have linked, makes no sense here.

Comment: Why does $w \in L$ imply $w \in \overline{L}$? Also can you clarify what you mean by complete? I would have assumed you are referring to the completeness of a class w.r.t. a type of reduction, but you link to Turing completeness. (comment reposted, fixed typo)

Comment: (1) Please get rid of the strange mix of LaTeX and UTF8 and use LaTeX exclucively. (2) Does anyone understand the question?

Comment: @Steven I've clarified what I mean by complete language.

Comment: A language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, but you wrote that a complete $L$ is a subset of $\mathrm{All}$, which is *not* $\Sigma^*$. I suspect your mathematical notation does not match your thoughts. In fact, $\lbrace L \subseteq \Sigma^*\rbrace$ is not even a valid definition. What is "All" supposed to be, written in words?

Comment: You did not explain what sort of reductions you have in mind. Many-to-one reduction? Turing reduction? Polynomial-time reduction?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Turing reduction. Also, I corrected my question, the first condition is that L is a subset of sigma star.

Comment: Do you think "All" is the language which contains all words, or the set of all languages? (You wrote something confusing that looks like "All is the set of all languages", but that doesn't make any sense.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer All is a collection of all languages above the alphabet ∑

Comment: Ok, I fixed the question they way I think it should read. Please have a look. Is this what you attempted to ask? If it is, then you misunderstood what a Turing reduction is. Every language is reducible to its complement.

Comment: @AndrejBauer your edit is correct, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this follow by a counting argument? Fix a language $C\subseteq \Sigma^*$. On the one had, the number of languages that are Turing-reducible to $C$ is at most $\aleph_0$. Indeed, there are only countably many Turing machines $M_C$ with access to the oracle $C$ (see @Ariel's answer [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67679/countably-many-oracle-turing-machines)). On the other hand, there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ languages $L$ over $\Sigma$. Hence, for every language $C\subseteq \Sigma^*$, there is a language $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$ that is not Turing-reducible to $C$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your attempt works.
$A \leq_T B$ doesn't imply $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, take for example
$$A = a^*, B = b^*.$$
We have $A \cap B = \emptyset$ as well as $A \leq_T B$.

Also, it generally *is* the case that $L \leq_T \overline{L}$ if I'm not mistaken.
Given $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$, define the oracle-machine $M_O$ with oracle $O$ deciding $\overline{L}$ as follows, given $w \in \Sigma^*$

- run $O$ on $w$
- accept $w$ if $O$ rejects $w$
- reject $w$ if $O$ accepts $w$

It can be verified that $L(M_O) = L$, thus $L \leq_T \overline{L}$.

Comment: is there a solution without using an Oracle machine?

Comment: Well, Turing reductions are defined in terms of oracle machines. So probably not.

Comment: What if I first prove that given f and a language L2, f can be used as a reduction function from L1 to L2 for only one language?

Comment: Not sure if that would show it.

Comment: Did you already read Bader Abu Radi answer below? That seems like a really nice solution.